# Evento RowDataBound en gridview

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente codigo en c# lo que necesito es mostrar los datos de un query en una celda de un gridview para ello uso el metodo RowDataBound.

datos que quiero mostrar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el codigo completo

```html
sql="Select cantidad from tabla";
SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cm1.CommandTimeout = 0;
SqlDataReader dr;
dr = cm1.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    double eficiencia = 0.0;
    double resul = 0.0;
    while (dr.Read())
    {
    eficiencia = eficiencia = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(0))/26;
        resul = eficiencia * 100;  
    }
    if (resul > 100)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "100%";
    }
    else
    {
        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = resul.ToString("00") + "%";
    }
}
else
{
    e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "0";
}
```

El problema es que solo me muestra el ultimo dato y en el header del gridview, aclaro que el gridview ya tiene datos solo quiero agregar esta otra columna con esta informacion aparte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo nada. Porque si tenes un reader, haces de ese reader un datatable (que es lo mismo, en otro formato), Porque despues lo pasa a un array (que es lo mismo, en otro formato) y donde es que tenes el problema y cual es mas claramente el problema?

Comment: o sea, que quiere decir no me funciona?

Comment: @gbianchi ya edite la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a simplicar tu codigo, ya que creo que estas haciendo un monton de cosas de mas (y al final, vamos a ver porque te esta dando error)

```
sql="Select cantidad from tabla";
SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cm1.CommandTimeout = 0;
SqlDataReader dr;
dr = cm1.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    double eficiencia = 0.0;
    double resul = 0.0;
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        eficiencia = reader.GetInt32(0) / 26;
        resul = eficiencia * 100;  
    }
    if (resul > 100)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "100%";
    }
    else
    {
        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = resul.ToString("00") + "%";
    }
}
else
{
    e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "0";
}
```

Este codigo hace lo que vos queres, sin pasar por un vector o un datatable, usando solamente el reader, que para eso lo tenes y lo abriste y lo podes aprovechar.

Ahora, yendo a tu error en particular en tu codigo, el codigo para acceder a cada fila es correcto, y z no esta teniendo el length, si no un valor distinto para cada posición. Lo que habria que ver en este caso, es que viene en tu datatable, ya que acceder a la fila columna de esa forma es correcto.

Comment: gracias me muestra este error "La conversión especificada no es válida." aqui: eficiencia = reader.GetInt32(0) / 26;

Comment: Puede que no sea GetInt32 lo que necesitas. No se que valores vienen ahi.

Comment: eficiencia = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(0)); lo resolvi asi, pero solo me esta mostrando el ultimo valor de los registros

Comment: si.. porque es lo que hace tu codigo. Vos queres que resul sea igual a que?

Comment: quiero que me muestre todos los resultados del query, no el ultimo registro, e.Row.Cells[4].Text es una columna de un gridview y ahi me debe mostrar todos los resultados de la imagen que añadi

Comment: este codigo esta dentro del metodo RowDataBound de un gridview

Comment: Ah para, pero eso no es lo que dijiste arriba. Nunca nombraste un gridview, nunca dijiste que querias mostrarlo por pantalla ni nada de eso. Tene en cuenta que no vemos lo que haces. Solo interpretamos el problema de tu pregunta. Y vos decias que no lo podias pasar a un array. En tal caso, si es asi, a tu pregunta le falta mucha informacion. Tenes la grilla creada por ejemplo?

Comment: si, ya esta creada con otro query solo necesito añadir estos registros y para eso uso el metodo RowDataBound

Comment: O sea.. tu pregunta es nada que ver con lo que escribiste. Vos necesitas llenar un gridview con datos. nada de un array ni otra cosa. Por eso tu codigo esta bien. Si esto esta dentro de un rowdatabound, no se ejecuta por cada fila? estas haciendo esto por cada fila? y cual valor queres mostrar? :(

Comment: creo que el error debe estar en while (dr.Read()) ya que resul va reemplazando su valor con cada iteracion

Comment: Eso es lo que te dije varios comentarios arriba y no lo entendiste...

Comment: entonces que podria hacer para evitar eso? gracias

Comment: Creo que deberias revisar lo que queres hacer. hacer un [mcve]. Especificar si esto es para un control web o winform o wpf. y mostrar como vienen tus datos, y como queres que queden. Yo sigo sin entender que pretendes de todo esto